# how to maintain an animate background and have page scroll over it?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Webpage has a static background, I want the animations to also remain static while the contents of the page scroll. Can this be done? Currently when the page scrolls so do the animations

Here is a crude example I have whipped up. This is my first time using  css-animations. I have been searching for the answer but have only really found animations with scroll events.

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://img15.deviantart.net/1294/i/2010/260/9/8/sample_background_001_by_professormegaman-d2yxb7g.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index:-2;
}

 img{
    width:100px;
}

.car-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 86%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
    
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-name: goRight;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
  -moz-animation-duration: 15s;
  -moz-animation-name: goRight;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


.car-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: blue;
    
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: goLeft;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;  
 -moz-animation-name: goLeft;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes goRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(700px,0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes goRight {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  }

  to {
    -moz-transform: translate(700px,0);
  }
}

 @keyframes goLeft{
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(700px,0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes goLeft{
  from {
    -moz-transform: translate(700px,0);
  }

  to {
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div class="animation-container">
       <div class="car-right">
           <img class="car-right-image"src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/car-png-10.png" alt="car">
       </div>
       <div class="car-left">
           <img class="car-left-image"src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/car-png-10.png" alt="car">
       </div>
       
    </div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
    <div>Content here</div>
   </body>
  
  
  </html>
```

Comment: Please don't change the snippet/code block in question based on the answer. It would confuse future readers as to what was the problem in the first place. Please rollback your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
.animation-container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}
```